# Increase row number by fixed amount in Excel

Tags: excel

I am struggling to find a way to increase row number in external excel source file.

Let's say I have `M4`, in which I want to have the value from `naujas.xlsx` Worksheet `C3005` cell.

`M5` should show value from `C3029`. So the row count should increase by `24`.

I have tried using `INDIRECT`, `OFFSET` and `INDEX`.

It would be best if this would work with INDEX as it allows the external file to be not loaded.
I want to be able to drag the formula down.

```
=OFFSET("[naujas.xlsx]Worksheet!$C$3005",ROW()+24,0,1,1)
=INDEX('C:\Users\user\Desktop[naujas.xlsx]Worksheet'!$C:$C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*24+3003)
```

This gives me an `error`.

[image: error]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try just typing in the formula sometime copy paste adds bad unseen characters.

Comment: Tried, same. Fails near the indicated $C,

Comment: Anybody, please?

Comment: try putting `''` around the workbook sheet `'[naujas.xlsx]Worksheet'!$C:$C`  Also make sure you put the folder location `'C:\MyFolder[naujas.xlsx]Worksheet'!$C:$C`

Comment: still fails :$C, part https://preview.ibb.co/m5OO2J/excel.png

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: nope, it works for me. Sorry.

Comment: Seems it needed \ before [naujas.xlsx] , in the comments it's removed, that's why it was failing.

Answer (score 0):

@Scott Craner was correct...

=INDEX('C:\Users\user\Desktop[naujas.xlsx]Worksheet'!$C:$C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*24+3003)

Is correct .